# Docker can't connect to Websocket PHP

Tags: symfony, docker, websocket, containers

I'cant connect to WebSocket using Docker Containers

My docker-compose.yml:

```
`
 version: "2"
 services:
db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    volumes:
        - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "qwerty"
        MYSQL_DATABASE: "web_face"
        MYSQL_USER: "web_face"
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: "qwerty"
php:
    build: php7-fpm
    ports:
        - 9000:9000
        - 3333:3333
    links:
        - db:mysqldb
    volumes:
        - ../www/:/var/www/symfony
        - ../logs/symfony:/var/www/symfony/app/logs
        - ../logs/php:/data/log/phpfpm/
nginx:
    build: nginx
    ports:
        - 80:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - php
    volumes:
        - ../logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
```

But when I'm trying to connect Rachet Websocket server I have error:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you changed the nginx configuration to handle the websocket handshake correctly?

You need a configuration similar to the following:

```
server {
    listen       80;

    upstream websocket {
        server php:9000;
    }    

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://websocket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

        proxy_connect_timeout 7d;
        proxy_send_timeout 7d;
        proxy_read_timeout 7d;
    }
}
```

You can read more about it in the [nginx documentation](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/)